# Bottles of beer in level 10

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm stuck on a 15-keystroke puzzle in Level 10:

[image: puzzle]

My register contains:

[image: registry]

My keyboard of available VIM commands is:

[image: keyboard]

I'm concerned I made this puzzle impossible by doing other puzzles in between: I come out exactly one keypress over par, and if I had the ability to re-yank the text I need and put one in the `""` register I'd be good. Sadly this text comes from a puzzle where you had to delete the text rather than yank it, and there's no place you can free-form paste your text; so I don't see a way to change where it sits in my registers.

The best sequence I can arrive at is:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"3P</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>"3p</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>"7p</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>"4p</kbd>

This comes out to 16 keystrokes which is one over par.

I can't think of a way to optimize the motion commands, and I can't think of a way to shorten the pastes without rearranging my registers, which I don't seem to be able to do.

Any tips for what it is I'm overlooking? Or have I messed up my save file?

Comment: I've gone pretty far back in the game looking for one of those fragments of text in any previous puzzle, no cigar so far.

Comment: I ended up reverting to a previous save and being more cautious with my registers. :/

Comment: where did you get the 99 bottles text from?

Comment: how did you managed to get `<NL>` for your beers text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 at the start is unnecessary. You don't need to be at the start of a line to paste above it.